# Concurrent message processing design controversy

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns, concurrency, jms

Recently I had designed a system to process health data using JMS using Oracle Advanced Queuing (AQ). The message must contain Patient Info such as Name, Health Card Number, etc. In addition the message may contain Patient Immunization record(s). I am using Spring Boot and I was able to process those messages concurrently by configuring multiple Message Listeners (up to 30). So I was able to gain a performance. However those messages are processed out of it chronological sequence causing data inconsistency. For example Message A represents new Patient record and message B represents an update to Patient created with message A. If processed subsequently (Message A and then Message B) the result is consistent with the upstream system. However if processed concurrently the results are not sync with reality (Message B may get processed before Message A). 
Clearly I shall not start processing Message B if there Message A. Let's say I have means to determine it (each message has event timestamp and status). But how to practically implement it? 
I would appreciate if anybody shares their experience. The actual technology does not matter, I am looking for some sort of Design pattern

Comment: @JustinBertram I am using Oracle Advanced Queuing (AQ). I was thinking about message grouping but it has to be part of one transaction as per Oracle. In my situation it is not possible, I do not control how messages are sent.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with JMS as the technology and you can't use message grouping then I see two basic ways to deal with this.

**Serialize all message processing**

By serializing all message processing you'll ensure that nothing is processed out-of-order. However, this could result in a significant performance reduction.

**Retry Out-of-Order Messages**

When you discover that you're processing a message out-of-order you could simply rollback the consumption of that message and configure a redelivery delay under the assumption that eventually the message which is "ahead" of the current message will be processed within the delay time. Most JMS brokers support multiple redeliveries of the same message sometimes even with increasingly long redelivery delays and also eventually the ability to put undeliverable messages into a "dead-letter" queue of some kind after a certain number of delivery attempts. The benefit here is that you can continue processing messages concurrently (with all the performance benefits that concurrency provides), and you only have to deal with out-of-order messages when the order is actually broken. The down-side is that you may waste some time re-processing some of the same messages multiple times, and you will need to establish some kind of process to deal with messages that are ultimately deemed undeliverable (although you may have to do this anyway).

Answer (score 0):

One way to gain performance without sacrificing order is to distribute your data across multiple *non-overlapping topics*. So Patient A and Patient B could go on different topics, but an update for Patient A would only go on Patient A's topic.

How ? One way to start is to use the patient's last name's first letter as topic. So all of patient Miller's messages go on topic M while John Doe's go on topic D. Of course, this distribution isn't ideal (not much work for subscriber 'X') but you could also use the hash code of the full name modulo 30, for example. Or if you have an ID, use the last 2 digits of the ID to publish and subscribe to topics 00 to 99.

In case you are concerned about loosing messages, use JMS durable subscriptions or setup up X number of queues instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the discussion. My final decision was as suggested by @Justin Bertram to simply send message back to the queue with delay option. Oracle Advance Queuing allows to en-queue message with delay option.